# UIView not updating in iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am new to iPhone App development, below is ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self updateMyView];

}

- (IBAction)clickButtonResult:(id)sender
{
    enteredText = [textField text]; // Or textField.text

    NSLog(@"Number 1 : %i", number_1);
    NSLog(@"Number 2 : %i", number_2);
    NSLog(@"Entered Text is %@", enteredText);

    int NUM_RESULT = number_1 + number_2;
    verify_result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", NUM_RESULT];

    NSLog(@"Verify Result : %@", verify_result);
    NSString *final_result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [enteredText isEqualToString:verify_result]];
    int final_int_result = [final_result integerValue];


    if (final_int_result) {
        //result_label.text = @"Correct";
        NSLog(@"Correct");
        [self updateMyView];
    } else {
        //result_label.text = @"Wrong";
        NSLog(@"Wrong");
    }
}

- (int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)min maxNumber:(int)max
{
    return min + arc4random() % (max - min + 1);
}

- (void) updateMyView
{
    number_1 = [self getRandomNumberBetween:10 maxNumber:99];
    number_2 = [self getRandomNumberBetween:10 maxNumber:99];

    num_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number_1];
    num_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number_2];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *num_1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *num_2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *result_label;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

    int number_1;
    int number_2;
    NSString *verify_result;
    NSString *enteredText;
    BOOL display_result;
}

- (IBAction)clickButtonResult:(id)sender;

@end
```

After entering the correct result the UIView should be updated with updateMyView function but it is not happening.

Can anyone help here??

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your clickButtonResult method and single-stepped through to make sure a) it is being called and b) it is doing what you expect?  By the way, it is probably simpler to use `[textField.text intergerValue]` rather than convert the result to a string and compare the string.

Comment: see whether your update view function and clickresult is called by using break point

Comment: What is breakpoint, i am not getting understood here?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, start using Properties.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *num_1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *num_2;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number_1;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number_2;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *verifyResult;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *enteredText;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL displayResult;

- (IBAction)clickButtonResult:(id)sender;

@end
```

In ViewController.m code use self.{name of property}, for example self.textField for the textField property.

Now, go to Interface builder and connect the IBOutlet properties to the right objects. (click with right button on File's Owner)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `num_1.text` in `viewDidLoad` to make sure you have access to that label from your `UIViewController`.

So in `viewDidLoad`, just put something like

`num1.text = @"Updated from viewDidLoad"`

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - more information is needed to answer the question, and what you have provided is a reasonable debugging step, however it would be better as a comment to the question than an answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have connected `num_1` and `num_2` with the `UILabels` properly. It seems that you have not connected these.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `[self updateMyView];` outside the `if` statements in `clickButtonResult:` function
then it will update the view when click the button.

```
if (final_int_result) {
    //result_label.text = @"Correct";
    NSLog(@"Correct");

} else {
    //result_label.text = @"Wrong";
    NSLog(@"Wrong");
}
[self updateMyView];
```

Comment: I am getting the same Error and UIView is not updating
Error is 
"Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1"

Comment: The main point is you should `connect` the `UILabel` or `UIButton` in the `storyboard` to the correspond variable or method in ` ViewController.h` file,  use `assistant editor`, make sure have a dot in the circle which before the line number